# username in params always null in filter

Tags: grails

I am  using grails 2.2.0 to an application with login page and add users feature ,

Here is the authentication method in the contoller :

```
def auth()
{

    def user = AppUsers.findByUsernameAndPassword (params?.username , params?.password.encodeAsSHA())


    if(params.username==user?.username && params.password.encodeAsSHA()==user?.password/*.encodeAsSHA()*/)
    {

        flash.message =message(code:'user.log.suc',args:[params.username])
        session.user=params.username

        redirect (controller:'patients' , action:'list')

    }
    else
    {
        //render ('login failed in if')
        //flash.message='login failed'
        flash.message =message(code:'user.log.failed',args:[params.username])


        redirect (action:'login')
    }





}
```

and here is to check if the user is admin or not :

```
def beforeInterceptor = [action:this.&isUserAdmin , except :[/*'auth' ,*/ 'logout', 'login']]

def isUserAdmin ()
{


    sherifUser=params.username
    if (!params?.username?.empty)
    {
        //  println("session userrr " +session.user)
        def userRole =AppUsers.findByUsername(params.username)//(username :'${params.username}', role:'admin')
        println("userrole " + userRole.role)
        //session.setAttribute("${params.username}", userRole.role)
        session["${params.username}"] = userRole.role
        println("session role : " + session.getAttribute("${params.username}"))
        return true
    }

    else
    {
        flash.message ="username or password empty"
        render(action:'login')
    }
```

}

and I'm using a filter to check if the user got admin role or not before entering to the add users page , here is the filter :

```
class AdminFilters
```

{

```
def filters =
{
    adminOnly(controller:'appUsers', action: '(create|edit|show|list|update)')
    {
        before =
        {
            //  def sessions = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()
            println("params username" + params.username) // this always returns back null !!
            def userRole = AppUsers.findByUsername(params.username)
            println("useeeeeee in fillter role " + session["params.username"])

            if (userRole?.equalsIgnoreCase("user"))
            {
                flash.messsage= " this area for admins only"
                redirect (controller:'appUsers' , action:'login')
                return false
            }
            else
            {
                flash.messsage= " Welcome admin"
                redirect (controller:'appUsers' , action:'list')
            }
        }
        after =
        { Map model ->
        }
        afterView =
        { Exception e ->
        }
    }
}
```

}

what cause that always params.username is null in the filter , altough the auth() method is working perfect ?!!

Any clarifications ?

Thanks 
Sherif

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that your filter definition is not totally right.

`adminOnly(controller:'appUsers', action: '(create|edit|show|list|update)')`

Should be..

`adminOnly(controller:'appUsers', action: 'create|edit|show|list|update')`

**update..**

Another wild guess after looking at the code..
When your user is succesfully authenticated, in the auth() method you are putting the username into the session. The params.username is never set anymore after that! When you do a redirect like **redirect (controller:'patients' , action:'list')** you will loose your all params after the page has succesfully rendered. A solution would be to re-use the session.user in the adminOnly filter.

```
        println("username" + session?.user)
        def userRole = AppUsers.findByUsername(session?.user)
        println("useeeeeee in fillter role " + session.user)
```

Comment: Thanks Marco , ya this time it was fixed , i totally forgot about the seesion's user , for just confrming my information if i use forward or render i will not lose my params , only in redirect i'll lose them because it's making new request ,  right ?  thanks

Comment: When using a plain forward or render you will also loose your params. The params are available on the controller on every request. So if you do not want to loose them you will have to provide the forward / render methods with the params you will want to keep.